# Does ale give less of a hangover than a lager?

Tags: human-anatomy, metabolism, alcohol

I got into an argument surrounding beer type and hangover. Apparently there is a [opinion that ales give you less hangover than lagers](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/983/does-drinking-mainstream-mass-produced-lagers-give-you-a-worse-hangover-than-re) do (considering same alcohol content consumed).

My understanding is that a hangover is [nothing more than dehydration caused by alcohol](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/what-is-the-molecular-basis-of-hangovers). More alcohol per unit of mass - more dehydration.

**Is there any biological evidence to show that the same amount of alcohol consumed (with a different type of yeast) per same body mass would have different effects?**

Comment: Is there evidence other than the assertions by the posters that they do in fact cause a greater hangover? The question cannot be answered if the effect does not in fact exist.

Comment: @MarchHo that is essentially what I am looking for, some scientific explanation (or thesis or source) that would confirm it or dismiss it.

Comment: Not a direct answer to ale vs. lager, but there certainly is evidence that [different alcoholic beverage types have different hangover effects](http://www.wired.com/2009/12/dark-liquor-makes-for-worse-hangovers/), although [the effect size is probably small](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hangovers/expert-answers/hangover-prevention/faq-20057969)

Comment: @oreo I am not sure if that study would qualify since it is purely subjective. The researchers asked the participants how they feel. The same feeling in the bourbon drinker to the vodka drinker may have been rated weaker since we don't know if it is true or just different tolerances to discomfort. Maybe the vodka drinkers could handle discomfort better so rated all hang over effects weaker.

Comment: @dustin Yes, you're totally right about "Hangover Intensity" as  subjective measure, but the [study that Wired refers to](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1530-0277.2009.01116.x/full) gave participants vodka vs. bourbon vs. placebo randomly, so I don't see any reason to think that tolerances to discomfort would be different among the subject groups.

Comment: @oreo it is like sensitivity to pain though. Some people are total fine when they receive a 2 inch laceration and others going into shock over the site of blood. With the alcohol drinkers, I would like to see the vodka drinkers be giving bourbon and the vice verse a. If they then say it isn't worse or is worse depending on the group, one could then say it is plausible that dark liquor is worse.